# How to obtain confidence limits of predicted values in ARIMA?

Tags: forecasting

How can one obtain confidence limits of predicted values in ARIMA?

Answer (score 4):

One idea would be to use the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package in [R](http://www.r-project.org/):

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
fit
f <- forecast(fit,h=20)
f
plot(f)
```

You can also give auto.arima parameters to use, rather than allowing it to fit its own.  I'm not sure how to obtain confidence intervals for the historic period-- you could try 'rolling' through the dataset, producing 1-step ahead forecasts+confidence intervals.

Comment: Why would you want confidence intervals (or prediction intervals) for the historic period?

Comment: @Rob Hyndman: I don't know, but I wasn't 100% sure what Sharma D was asking for, so I answered it both ways.  Out of curiosity, how exactly does your forecast package calculate confidence intervals for arima models?  I recall reading somewhere that is some cases a simulation is used, but it's been a while since I've read the documentation.

Comment: Actually, the `forecast()` function just calls the `predict.Arima()` function which uses the psi method as explained by @IrishStat. For linear ARIMA models, there is no need to resort to simulation. For some nonlinear ETS models, simulation is used.

Comment: Thanks, Information provided was very much helpful. its very much easy in R than in SPSS. Regards

Comment: @RobHyndman in epidemic surveillance, for example, I'm currently want to use the CI to establish a threshold, e.g. when the count exceed that we flags it as an alarm. Does it make sense to do 'rolling' through the data set to obtain that?

Answer (score 3):

The confidence limits for an ARIMA forecast are based upon the PSI WEIGHTS . The PSI WEIGHTS are easily computed by representing the ARIMA MODEL as a pure MOVING AVERAGE MODEL. One should not be dependent upon software ( any software ! ) for answers.